# Unable to compile repository downloaded from server

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I created a source code repository with a branch, the source and branch are working fine, checking for pending changes everything went up to the repository with no problem.

It is assumed that uploading everything to the repository without problems should download without errors, but when a team member gets the project from the server, it fails to compile.

Mistakes go through this:

[image]

Why when obtaining the project some dlls are not loaded?

This is the repository you create with **TFS (Azure DevOps)**.

How can I force that when downloading the repository it downloads with all the dlls?

[image]

**On laptop everything works fine, this happens when someone else gets the project from server.**

Comment: Missing libraries?

Comment: @CaiusJard They are the references that are not downloaded

Comment: *How can I force that when downloading the repository it downloads with all the dlls?* - did they fail to download because they're not actually available? Set up a private nuget server with them on and download them from there?

Answer (score 0):

No sure how you add those reference into your project.
But if you do use nuget, then just simply restore the nuget packages

1. Right click on your solution
2. Click on Restore NuGet Packages

[image: Restore NuGet Packages]